# Metrics breakdown in Facebook app_insights,Not Working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, metrics, facebook-insights

I have a function like this.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $sessiondata,
        'GET',
        '/'.$appID.'/app_insights/'.$metric.''
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I want to return breakdowns of app_insights metrics ,,,
But unfortunately when i add breakdowns like this ,,every time ,,,its return empty object!!

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
        $sessiondata,
        'GET',
        '/'.$appID.'/app_insights/'.$metric.'',
        array (
            'breakdowns[0]' => 'age',
            'breakdowns[1]' => 'gender',
            'breakdowns[2]' => 'country',
        )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

is there any way to do this in proper way??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember that not every breakdown is available for every metric. Which metric you were trying?

I would try via Graph explorer and start from single breakdown, then add others
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer